# Storing image in plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can we store images in plist file. Where is this plist file stored? Can anyone give me an example? Answers will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `UIImage` doesn't implement the NSCoder protocol directly that is necessary for storage in plists.

But, it is fairly easy to add like below.

## UIImage+NSCoder.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIImage (MyExtensions)
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder;
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder;
@end
```

## UIImage+NSCoder.m

```
#import "UIImage+NSCoder.h"

@implementation UIImage (MyExtensions)

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
  [encoder encodeDataObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self)];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
  return [self initWithData:[decoder decodeDataObject]];
}

@end
```

When this has been added you will be able to store UIImages in plist with ie

```
// Get a full path to a plist within the Documents folder for the app
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask,
                                                     YES);
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/my.plist",
                                              [paths objectAtIndex:0]];

// Place an image in a dictionary that will be stored as a plist
[dictionary setObject:image forKey:@"image"];

// Write the dictionary to the filesystem as a plist
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:dictionary toFile:path];
```

*Note: I do not recommend doing this, unless you really want to, ie for really small images.*

Answer (score 5):

Always store the image path in the .plist, never the actual image. If you do, you'll take a performance hit. You want to load images as you need them, not all at once.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where and when these images are known to the application.

For images as part of the application bundler, [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=562294) may provide some insight. If you want to store images during the ***running*** of the application you can use the same concepts (user plist with relative paths to images).

-- Frank

Answer (score 0):

plist files are meant to store key-value pairs, not the resources of your application. The icons, images and forms are usually stored in a .xib file (see Interface Builder)