# iPhone - plist data type item empty but not nil

Tags: ios, iphone, dictionary, uiimage, plist

I use a plist file to store some data, and I have into that plist file an item whose type is Data. I use it to store a little UIImage.

When loading the NSDictonary including this item, I see that it's not null. But I never put anything into it, I'm sure (it's a default plist item).

```
UIImage* test = [dict objectForKey:@"miniImage"];
```

How can I check if that item contains something or not ?

Comment: How are you storing this image? UIImage doesn't implement the NSCoder protocol.   See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486705/storing-image-in-plist

Answer (score 0):

Do you check both nil or [NSNull null] since for value in dictionary, when it does not exist
it should be [NSNull null].
Just a guess.