# saving data in property list

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to save an array of objects in a property list.
i done it by using this method:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

DataObj *obj1 = [[DataObj alloc]initWithDataObj:@"Facebook" :@"yosi" :@"1234" :[UIImage imageNamed:@"blogger.png"] ];
DataObj *obj2 = [[DataObj alloc]initWithDataObj:@"Facebook2" :@"yosi2" :@"12345" :[UIImage imageNamed:@"blogger.png"] ];

self.list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:obj1,obj2,nil ];

[self.list writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES];
```

the fourth object in the DataObj is a image and i cant save it in a property list,there is any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using imageNamed, then I'm assuming the image is in your main bundle, in which case I would put the image name in the plist, and use imageNamed: again when when you read it.

The other option is to turn your image into something that is encodable, like an NSData object. When you read the property list back in, convert the data back into a UIImage.

Take a look at
[UIImagePNGRepresentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImagePNGRepresentation).

and [-initWithData:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/initWithData%3a)

Comment: the problem in the first solution that there is picture that aren't in the main bundle and the user add them, so i want to save this pic in the property list, so the solution in to use nsdata?

Comment: If the images aren't in the main bundle, then you're going to have some problems with imageNamed: Per the docs - "The name of the file. If this is the first time the image is being loaded, the method looks for an image with the specified name in the application’s main bundle."

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the UIImage to NSData before saving it.

```
 NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
```

Update: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486705/storing-image-in-plist) for a more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

Write the image to a file in the app's documents directory, and save the filename or the filepath to the image to the property list.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting `DataObj` objects into the array that you are then trying to save as a plist. Plist files can not contain arbitrary objects so this is not going to work.

The images are your secondary problem.

Answer (score -1):

Your `DataObj` class must adopt the [NSCoding protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSCoding) for archiving.  Take a look at [Encoding and Decoding Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000948-BCIHBJDE).

Comment: `NSArray`'s `writeToFile:atomically:` does not use `NSCoding` but property list serialization.