# Serialize a NSMutableArray that includes classes not implementing NSCoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, serialization, nsarray

I need to save an `NSMutableArray` to disk in order to store my application data. I know there are a lot of similiar questions out there but none of them I found covers my question.

I do not want to integrate Core Data just for saving one `NSMutableArray`. Normally I would go for implementing the `NSCoding` protocol and using `NSKeyedUnarchiver`. Unfortunately, my data model class has some foreign classes from a library which do not implement the `NSCoding` protocol.

So what is the best way for me to store my array?

This is what I tried but because of the given reasons it won't work:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <ForeignFramework/ForeignFramework.h>

@interface DEModelClass : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic,strong) ForeignFramework *foreignFramework;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSNumber *number1;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSNumber *number2;

@end


#define kEncodeKeyForeign   @"kEncodeKeyForeign"
#define kEncodeKeyImage      @"kEncodeKeyImage"
#define kEncodeKeyNumber1     @"kEncodeKeyNumber1"
#define kEncodeKeyNumber2     @"kEncodeKeyNumber2"


#pragma mark - NSCoding
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.foreignFramework   forKey:kEncodeKey];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.image  forKey:kEncodeKeyImage];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.number1 forKey:kEncodeKeyNumber1];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.number2 forKey:kEncodeKeyNumber2];

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        self.foreignFramework = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:kEncodeKeyForeign];
        self.image    = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:kEncodeKeyImage];
        self.number1   = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:kEncodeKeyNumber1];
        self.number2   = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:kEncodeKeyNumber2];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: How about using `NSUserDefaults` ?

Comment: Well NSUserDefaults is not really the right location to store a whole data array, right ?

Comment: Why not? One other option would be to create a `plist` file programmatically and store your data in it, and retrieve when needed. Check out [THIS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/CreatePropListProgram/CreatePropListProgram.html). Apple's own code to save data to `plist`.

Comment: There is no standard way to "serialize" an arbitrary class.  If the class is not one of those that the system knows how to deal with you must invent your own scheme, perhaps employing JSON.

Comment: The link I shared above along with [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486705/storing-image-in-plist) will handle `image`, `number1` and `number2`. Can't say anything about `foreignFramework `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `NSCoding` protocol and you can use it.

A. I assume that you know, which properties of the foreign classes to store. (Probably that data that let you re-instantiate instance objects at loading.) If not, there is no way to store them. And of course, Cocoa, `NSArray`, $whatever cannot know it. These are generic.

B. When you are done with selecting the properties to store, simply add a category to the foreign classes that do the job for you:

```
@interface ForeignClass (MyCodingAddition)
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)encoder;
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)decoder;
@end

@implementation ForeignClass (MyCodingAddition)
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)encoder
{
  [coder encodeObject:self.property withKey:…]
  …
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)decoder
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self)
  {
    self.property = [decode objectForKey:…];
    …
  }
  return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: Keine Sache, ist allerdings in Safari getippt.