# Saving image and its title on plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

How can I store an image and any string value in `plist` as dictionary.I
have created a `plist` file in the project,and
also how can i append the file with same `dictionary` of different image and name?

Comment: it duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486705/storing-image-in-plist

Comment: How do you get the image?

Comment: Do you pick the image from photo library or directly get the image from bundle?

Comment: no.. i fetch it from from flicker and save it in my object model

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link. It provides detail how to store image to plist

[Storing image in plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486705/storing-image-in-plist)

And for title to store you can add new key like below.

// Get a full path to a plist within the Documents folder for the app

```
NSString *titleStr = @"Title Of Image";
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask,
                                                     YES);
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/YOURPLIST.plist",
                                              [paths objectAtIndex:0]];

// Place an image in a dictionary that will be stored as a plist
[dictionary setObject:image forKey:@"image"];
[dictionary setObject:titleStr forKey:@"title"];

// Write the dictionary to the filesystem as a plist
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:dictionary toFile:path];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to write image & title to-gather in plist-

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PlistName.plist"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
    {
        path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"PlistName.plist"] ];
    }

    fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSMutableDictionary *dataDictionary=[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


    [dataDictionary setObject:ImageData forKey:image];
    [dataDictionary setObject:ImageTitle forKey:title];
    [dataDictionary writeToFile: path atomically:YES];
```

And read your image & title dictionary from plist like this-

```
- (NSDictionary * )readDataFromPlist()
{
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PlistName.plist"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSMutableDictionary *dataDictionary;

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
    {
        dataDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
       return dataDictionary;
    }else
        return nil;

}
```